# How to return empty view in controller if string is not null?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, if-statement, view, return

In my controller I have some code, and final part which is returning all results to my view is:

```
public ActionResult Index(SearchParameters parameters)
{
... some code ...
var view = new SpremenljivkeView
{
    Spremenljivke = matchingSpremenljivke,
    Search = parameters,
    TotalCount = matchingSpremenljivke.NumFound,
};

return View("../Login/Index", view);
}
```

Now I whant to send results in View if string in parameters (Internal number) are not empty or null. If is null, return empty value, if not return view with results.

I have try this:

```
...
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameters.Internal))
{
  var view = new SpremenljivkeView
  {
    Spremenljivke = matchingSpremenljivke,
    Search = parameters,
    TotalCount = matchingSpremenljivke.NumFound,
  };

  return View("../Login/Index", view);
}
```

But return View cannot be inside If sentece. Any idea how to correct this...

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to return `EmptyResult` in else part as Action nneds to return `ActionResult`:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameters.Internal))
{
  var view = new SpremenljivkeView
  {
    Spremenljivke = matchingSpremenljivke,
    Search = parameters,
    TotalCount = matchingSpremenljivke.NumFound,
  };

  return View("../Login/Index", view);
}
else
{
return new EmptyResult();
}
```

and if you want to return same view without values then return only view in else part:

```
return View("../Login/Index");
```